# Are Newton-Raphson and Newton conjugated gradient the same?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

As the question asks: Are Newton-Raphson and Newton conjugated gradient the same? I understand them as being so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they aren't. In fact, the Newton conjugated gradient method is a modified version of Newton's method (also called Newton-Raphson). It is a conjugate gradient algorithm which approximates the inverse of the local Hessian, while Newton's method works with the Hessian as is. Therefore, a common advantage is that it can converge faster than Newton's method.*

If you know Python, you can see code explaining how to use the method [here in SciPy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/tutorial/optimize.html). Reading the explanations, formulas and code there, you will be able to understand the steps of the method and how it is different from the standard Newton method.

*In ad-hoc cases. For example, computing the inverse of the Hessian matrix can become quite expensive for large matrices.